# Firefox 68.12.0esr (64-bit) it crashes on loading web pages

Tags: firefox, crash

Firefox 68.12.0esr (64-bit) tab crashes on loading web pages.

Centos 7 host
VirtualBox VM
Centos 7 Guest with 3d enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Some web pages (e.g. LinkedIN, Ebay, Google drive,  and several others) will have a tab crash on loading the page.  It appears this is related to a 3D and OpenGL issue.

Work around:

- Shutdown guest.
- Go to guest configuration
- Select "display" tab
- Uncheck 2d and 3d check boxes.
- Restart guest.

Strace also reveals:

```
8962  21:02:49 open("/usr/lib64/firefox/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
9027  21:02:55 open("/usr/lib64/firefox/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

9027  21:03:38 write(2, "OpenGL Warning: ", 16) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
9027  21:03:38 write(2, "Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.", 76) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
9027  21:03:38 write(2, "\n", 1)        = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
9027  21:03:38 write(2, "OpenGL Warning: ", 16) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
8975  21:03:38 write(2, "[Parent 8962, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-68.12.0/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 727\n", 169) = 169
8975  21:03:38 write(2, "[Parent 8962, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-68.12.0/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 727\n", 169 <unfinished ...>
8975  21:03:39 write(2, "[Parent 8962, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (42): Connection reset by peer: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-68.12.0/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358\n", 187 <unfinished ...>
```